# JS acting weirdly when trying to count number of certain values in an array

Tags: javascript

i recreated the issue on simple example

```js
const cards = ["2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "jack", "queen", "king", "ace"];
let sortedranks = [0, 0, 1, 1, 2];

function count(array, value) {
  let cnt = 0;
  for (i of array) {
    if (i == value) cnt++;
  }
  return cnt;
}

for (i in cards) {
  console.log(sortedranks);
  console.log(i);
  console.log(count(sortedranks, i));
  console.log(count(sortedranks, i) === 2);
}
```

when running this, thats what i'm getting on first iteration

```
[0, 0, 1, 1, 2]
0
2
false
```

whole other part of this html file is a blank from VS Code, my question in very simple, if count(sortedranks, i) on first and second iterations is equal to 2, then why count(sortedranks, i) === 2 on the same iterations is false? and how this can be fixed?

Comment: The issue you're encountering is due to a mismatch between the data types being compared.

Comment: You are using `for...in` which iterates keys of an object, not the values. This shouldn't be used on arrays (though it is more stable than it used to be)

Comment: It's because you don't declare `i` with `let`, so it's treated as a global variable. Always use `let` or `const`, as in `for (let i in cards) {`. When your `count()` function runs it overwrites what's in `i` in your for loop.

Comment: In your code, the i variable in the for...in loop represents the indices of the cards array, which are strings. However, in the count function, you are comparing i (which represents the indices) with the value parameter, which is also a string.

Since you're using the === operator for comparison, it checks for both value and type equality. In JavaScript, comparing a string with a number using === will always result in false because the types are different.

Comment: @RameshKumar no.

Comment: @RameshKumar - it's not to do with types, `sortedranks` does return a number. @AndyRay above your second comment explains the real issue